# let me know or tell me

Tags: meaning, word-choice

My work basically is to answer customers' questions by emails and I use the phrase' tell me' at my work, but my boss said it's too casual , I should use the phrase "let me know ", is it ture? I don't really understand what the difference is. For example, if I'm asking for a customer's address or his/her waist size, which one should I say?

Comment: That is unanswerable without further details, context, examples of what you have in mind.  In some cases "tell me" is fine.  But there are other cases where "let me know" is the more appropriate expression.  "Let me know if that helps."  "Let me know how you get on."  "Please let me know some further details."

Comment: If it's information to be provided later, use "let me know" or "let us know" or "include" ("When you reply to the email, remember to let us know your address" / "...remember to include your address").  If it's information you need right away, "tell" and "let me know" both work, but must be preceded by "could you..." or "can you..." for politeness.  So, "could you tell me your address" or "could you let me know your address" ("what is your address?" is also usually fine though), and "could you tell me your waist size" or "could you let me know your waist size".

Comment: Please put details/clarifications in the post. You can [edit] your post at any time. If you could provide an example dialogue/conversation you have, that would be helpful too. See [Details, Please](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/439/36187) and the [Contributor's Guide (Asking)](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4785/36187) for more tips and examples.

Answer (score 4):

"Let me know" is asking to be informed. As "let" means to *allow*, this is a **polite** way of asking to be kept informed, because you are asking for *permission* to know.

"Tell me" is a **demand**, and so less polite. You can certainly make it more polite by saying "*please* tell me", but you are still asking for information rather than asking to be allowed that information. "Please let me know" would be even more polite.

Comment: Thank you. I see, plus, Can I say' could you please let me know'' or is it going to be weird for a question like 'could you please let me know your address"?

Answer (score 2):

If it's information to be provided later, use "let me know" or "let us know" or "include" ("When you reply to the email, remember to let us know your address" / "...remember to include your address").

If it's information you need right away, "tell" and "let me know" both work, but must be preceded by "could you..." or "can you..." for politeness. So, "could you tell me your address" or "could you let me know your address" ("what is your address?" is also usually fine though), and "could you tell me your waist size" or "could you let me know your waist size".

Comment: I see, thank you. And I understand if I want to pick up my girlfriend for dinner, but she doesn't know if she is going to work late, I can use the phrase "let me know if you can get off work early"  is that right?

Comment: @M_SO Yes, that's right.